# Keycloak user storage provider and RoleStorageProvider implementation

Tags: authentication, keycloak, roles, user-roles, keycloak-services

I wrote my own UserStorageProvider that loads user data and external jdbc storage, can view, edit, create and delete users. It also creates a mapping for each user with roles from the repository. But, there is a difficulty. I want to load all the roles from the repository into the keycloak realm so that I can later make new role mappings for users. Add, edit and remove roles. I found that there is a RoleStorageProvider and a Factory for it. I wrote an implementation, when loading this provider is loaded into keycloak, but I don’t know how to use it further inside the administrator console. Maybe someone will tell?

public class CustomRoleStorageProvider implements
RoleStorageProvider,
RoleLookupProvider,
RoleProvider
{

```
protected EntityManager em;
protected ComponentModel model;
protected KeycloakSession session;

public CustomRoleStorageProvider(KeycloakSession session, ComponentModel model) {
    this.model = model;
    this.session = session;
    this.em = session.getProvider(JpaConnectionProvider.class, "user-store").getEntityManager();
}
```

// { implementation of all provider methods here ..}

}

public class CustomRoleStorageProviderFactory implements RoleStorageProviderFactory {

```
public static final String PROVIDER_ID = "JDBC ROLES";
@Override
public CustomRoleStorageProvider create(KeycloakSession keycloakSession, ComponentModel componentModel) {
    log.info(">>>>>> Creating Roles factory >>>>>>");
    return new CustomRoleStorageProvider(keycloakSession, componentModel);
}

@Override
public String getId() {
    return PROVIDER_ID;
}

@Override
public void close() {
}
```

}